# iOS and Android: Can you link between apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, hyperlink, temenos-quantum

We're developing an app where we'd like to be able to link to other apps from within ours.

The questions (both for iOS and Android):

- Can you put a link in one app that can launch another app?
- If so, does that other app have to be modified in any way to 'accept' that link?
- If so, can one app tell if another app is installed or not (as if it's not we could instead show a link to the app store)?

(If dev platform matters, this is an app being built upon Kony)

Comment: For Android, it uses `Intents`.  Not sure about IOS.

Comment: For iOS you can launch the other app using an app url, the launched app needs to make a few changes which only take 5 minutes.

Comment: @Mungbeans so, just to clarify, if we want to link to and launch a 3rd party app, that 3rd party has to modify the app to allow that?

Comment: Yes, the launched app needs to enable itself to be capable of being launched by a unique app url.

Comment: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can link between the two apps by using the "Deeplink" or "Appservice" functionality.  In the Kony platform, you define the Deeplink function as part of the project properties, and you can read specific examples in the Kony documentation, as well as learn more information on the Kony Developer portal in the Forum section under this topic:
http://developer.kony.com/konyforum/viewtopic.php?id=1097